# Error retrieving image from URL in Google Apps Script but only on some spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have Google Sheets spreadsheets that perform a lot of (small file-size) image retrieval using `SpreadsheetApp.newCellImage()` via code similar to the below:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const image = SpreadsheetApp.newCellImage()
    .setSourceUrl("https://static-00.iconduck.com/assets.00/perspective-dice-random-icon-469x512-mm6xb9so.png")
    .setAltTextTitle("Image")
    .build();

  sheet.getRange("A1").setValue(image);
}
```

Just recently I noticed that these spreadsheets would get an error when trying to apply the image to a cell:

```markdown
Exception: Error retrieving image from URL or bad URL
```

This would happen with ANY image I try and on ANY cell. It would fail at the `setValue(image)` call.

Here's the kicker. If I tried running the exact function above in a NEW spreadsheet, **it would work with no issues**. But running it in my existing spreadsheets would fail.

If I try and duplicate my existing spreadsheet (`File` > `Make a copy`) it would also fail on the duplicated spreadsheet. I also looked at [usage limits](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits) for Google Sheets but didn't find anything relevant to my issue.

Video reproduction of the issue: https://imgur.com/a/qJfCC4N

Note how I run the above function in a completely new spreadsheet and it works, but I copy-paste it into an existing spreadsheet that is causing errors and it fails on that spreadsheet.

Any ideas?

Comment: As you say **a lot of**, does it relate to rate limit (of the server hosting the image)? Besides, please provide a [minimal reproductive example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @idfurw No, this is happening with any image, not only with images from the server that the spreadsheets usually retrieve the images from.

Comment: @idfurw The only minimal reproducible example I can provide is the code snippet that's already in the question. I also just now updated my question with a video reproduction.

Comment: I am not sure about this. But try this in your Fashion Tracker. Try adding `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request` in `appsscript.json`. Refer: [Setting Scopes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes)

Comment: @ShriHariL Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I opened up the `appsscript.json` and it looks like that scope is already there in the `oauthScopes` array.

Comment: In this case, I think that it is required to correctly replicate your current issue. By this, the reason for your current issue might be able to be understood. So, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating your current issue?

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I tested directly your `myFunction`, I could replicate your issue. It seems that in this case, even when the image URL is changed, the same error occurs. Unfortunately, I cannot find a clear reason for this issue. I apologize for this. But, when I copied your provided Spreadsheet with manual operation and a script, `myFunction` worked for both copied Spreadsheets.

Comment: In your question, you say `If I try and duplicate my existing spreadsheet (File > Make a copy) it would also fail on the duplicated spreadsheet.`. So, how about copying your Spreadsheet with a script and testing it again? I'm worried whether in your current Spreadsheet, other issues might occur with other methods of the script.

Answer (score 1):

One quick workaround would be to insert an `image()` formula in the cell instead of inserting the image directly. Try this:

```js
function insertImageInCellA1() {
  const url = 'https://static-00.iconduck.com/assets.00/perspective-dice-random-icon-469x512-mm6xb9so.png';
  const formula = `=image("${url}")`;
  ss.getRange('Test!A1').setFormula(formula);
}
```

See [image()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093333), [Range.setFormula()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula) and [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: This workaround does work, thank you!! I am infinitely curious about why the regular method isn't working, but I'll accept this answer if nothing else works.